# Select all dates with missing dates SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I have three tables which are `UserInfo`, `Departments` & `CheckInOut`. And by the following procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetLogs] 
@DateFrom datetime, 
@DateTo datetime, 
@UserID varchar(max) 

as  
begin 
declare @Query varchar(max) 
set @Query =  'SELECT Badgenumber, Name, min(checktime) as [Check Time],    CHECKTYPE as [Check Type] 
    from USERINFO  
        inner join DEPARTMENTS as dept
            on USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID = dept.DEPTID 
        inner join CHECKINOUT
            on USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
    where CHECKINOUT.USERID in (' + @UserID + ')  and CHECKTIME between ''' + CONVERT(varchar, ( @DateFrom )) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar, ( @DateTo  )) +  ''' 
    group by CHECKINOUT.userid, USERINFO.Badgenumber, USERINFO.Name, CHECKTYPE, CONVERT(varchar, checktime, 101) order by CHECKINOUT.userid'

    print @Query 
    Exec (@Query) 
  end  

exec spGetLogs'01/14/2015', '03/31/2015', 1
```

Which results as following

```
1001    James Biser 2015-01-14 06:42:47.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-17 06:38:06.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-18 06:42:58.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-19 06:38:00.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-20 06:43:45.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-21 06:42:14.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-22 06:41:43.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-24 07:25:31.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-25 06:39:14.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-26 06:35:48.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-27 06:39:07.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-28 06:49:51.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-29 06:47:28.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-01-31 07:21:18.000 I 
1001    James Biser 2015-02-01 06:33:34.000 I
```

I need to show that employee is absent on the dates which are missing here like between 14 & 17, 15 and 16 January date is missing. I need to show James Biser as absent on those missing dates.

Comment: You shouldn't start your procedure with sp, it's meant for system procedures.

Comment: In addition to what JamesZ wrote, you need a left join with a calendar table to see the dates that are missing from your data. Also, there is no need for dynamic sql in this case. use a table valued parameter to pass the user id to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table if dates, that contains a row for each day you'll ever need (f. ex. 1.1.2000 - 31.12.2099). With that you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  U.Badgenumber, 
  U.Name, 
  D.[Date],
  C.Checktime,
  C.Checktype
from 
  USERINFO U
  join DEPARTMENTS as D
    on U.DEFAULTDEPTID = D.DEPTID
  cross join Dates D
  outer apply (
    select top 1 CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE
    from CHECKINOUT C 
    where 
      U.USERID = C.USERID and 
      C.CHECKTIME >= D.[Date] and 
      C.CHECKTIME < dateadd(day, 1, D.[Date])
    order by
      C.CHECKTIME asc
  ) C
where 
  U.USERID in (' + @UserID + ')  and 
  D.[Date] >= ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @DateFrom, 112 ) + ''' AND
  D.[Date] < ''' + CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(day, 1, @DateTo), 112) +  ''' 
group by 
  U.USERID, 
  U.Badgenumber, 
  U.Name
order by 
  U.USERID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a solution like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
     SELECT CAST('2015-03-01' AS datetime) AS d
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-02'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-03'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-04'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-07'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-08'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-09'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-10'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-02-27'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-02-28'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-20'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-19'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-17'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-16'
), t1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        MIN(t.d) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) minD, 
        MAX(t.d) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) maxD
    FROM 
        t
)
, CTE(d, i) AS (
    SELECT TOP(1) t1.minD, 1
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, CTE.d), CTE.i + 1
    FROM CTE 
        JOIN
        t1  ON CTE.d < t1.maxD
)
SELECT CTE.d
FROM 
    CTE
    LEFT JOIN
    t ON CTE.d = t.d
WHERE
    t.d IS NULL
ORDER BY i
```

That it's result is this:

```
d
2015-03-05 00:00:00.000
2015-03-06 00:00:00.000
2015-03-11 00:00:00.000
2015-03-12 00:00:00.000
2015-03-13 00:00:00.000
2015-03-14 00:00:00.000
2015-03-15 00:00:00.000
2015-03-18 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the result set of your stored procedure into a table (I'm calling it GetLogs) or temp table or combine the code below with your stored procedure (CTE,Function etc) then you can present the days the person was absent.

```
DECLARE @CHECKTIME datetime
SET @CHECKTIME = (SELECT MIN([Check Time]) FROM GETLOGS)
SELECT @CHECKTIME AS [CHECKTIME] INTO CT1
WHILE @CHECKTIME < (SELECT MAX([CHECK TIME])+1 FROM GetLogs)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CT1 SELECT @CHECKTIME
SET @CHECKTIME = (@CHECKTIME + 1) 
END
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CHECKTIME,101) FROM CT1 WHERE CONVERT
(VARCHAR,CHECKTIME,101) NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Check Time],101)
FROM GETLOGS)
```